# Force line-ending in print function to be the same as original string in python-shell Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, pandas

I am using [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) to run some scripts on my `nodejs` server
The only way to get results out is to `print` to get the data as a `message`

I am trying to do (within my python script, `df` is a `pandas` dataframe) :

```py
print(df.to_csv())
```

When I send out the result, it does not send the actual string I'm expecting from `to_csv` (with `\n` as the linebreak character). Going through `print`, I am getting the output of the console with `↵` as the linebreak character which basically throws out my downstream processing.

Is there a way (barring reimplementing `to_csv`) to get what I want ?

Comment: Do you want to replace `newline character(\n)` with `line break(↵)`?

Comment: No I am getting line break and i want new line instead. But not keen on using a `replace` function of any kind as I should be able to get directly what I want I'm assuming.

Comment: `.to_csv()` by default gives `\n`.

Comment: yes it's by going through `print()` that it gets changed to line breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue, just use `print(repr(whatever_string_you_were_trying_to_print))`